# How can i revert a git commit --amend -m without losing my original hashcode and the code i supposed to commit?

Tags: git, commit, undo, git-amend

I need to revert a wrong git commit --amend -m

1. did git commit without -m
2. did git commit --amend -m "commit message"
3. git commit --amend -m "commit message" changed my previous commit instead of the one i supposed to commit.

is it possible to revert to before the step 1 without losing my original hashcode or the code i supposed to commit?

commit is not pushed yet btw

Comment: hint: `git reflog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git reset --soft "HEAD@{1}"
git commit -m "commit message"
```

`HEAD@{1}` [means](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrefnamegtltngtemegemmaster1em) "find where `HEAD` was before the current commit". You can verify it's really the previous (unmodified) commit using `git reflog` and `git show "HEAD@{1}"`.

Comment: I did something wrong. I used the git terminal inside eclipse then i switched to the normal git console and i end up losing a couple of classes. Not sure what happen exactly.